# How to print the outputs of LSTM layer after the training is finished?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can anyone give me a suggestion how to output the 3 sequences of LSTM layer after the training is finished?

```
inputs = Input(shape=(100, 1, ))
lstm = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, y)
```

Another question: if the code written as following

```
inputs = Input(shape=(100, 1, ))
lstm = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, y)
```

Then an error occurred:

```
TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found:
Tensor("add_1:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)
```

Can anyone give me any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: your model runs fine for me. The  first question is not clear. What do you mean by "output the 3 sequences of LSTM"?

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you want now. You would like to print the output of the 
LSTM layer (given some value for the input)

Here is how I would do it ( there are at least 3 ways outlined [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#How%20can%20I%20obtain%20the%20output%20of%20an%20intermediate%20layer?) )

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import LSTM, Input, TImeDistributed, Dense
from keras.models import Model

X = np.random.rand(10, 100, 1)
y = np.random.rand(10, 100, 1)


inputs = Input(shape=(100, 1, ))
lstm = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X, y)
```

this function allows us to see the output of the lstm layer
Notice that we can change which we layer we want to see outputs for 
but just changing the 1 in `[model.layers[1].output]` to something else (2 for instance).

```
lstm_out = K.function([model.inputs[0], 
                        K.learning_phase()], 
                       [model.layers[1].output])
# pass in the input and set the the learning phase to 0
print(lstm_out([X, 0]))
```

Comment: Awesome. You can mark it as answer so others can benefit too.